# dkpg "diversion" error after trying to install nvidia-340

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, dpkg, 18.04

I have a Dell with a Core I5 and a GeForce820M.

After upgrading to 18.04 LTS I tried to upgrade the nvidia drivers by running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

which is the recommended driver for my GPU.

The problem is the installation failed, I didn't record the fail reasons and now any `dpkg` or `apt-get` commands I try to run say that I should run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I tried running that but it kept getting stuck at

```
Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic
```

Finally I managed to complete it, but when I tried to install the nvidia-340 package again I got an error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-340_340.106-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib' with
  different file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1', not allowed
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-340_340.106-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new nvidia-340 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-340_340.106-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same hang onthe exact same kernel while trying to install nvidia-390.
Following [this thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1036167/linux/stuck-trying-to-intall-nvidia-390-ubuntu-18-04-lts-/post/5264934/#5264934) it seems like the install is waiting for a password, so I blind-typed it several times and the installation continued.

You should probably purge the package you installed and try to re-install it. Installing as root user would eliminate the need to type the password.